# Table doesn't exist error when execuitng dynamic sql with sp_executesql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

If I open a connection to a database, for example, with SSMS, and I run a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM MySchema.MyTable
```

the query is executed without error.

If I run it as dynamic sql like this

```
declare var @qry nvarchar(200);
set @qry = N'SELECT * FROM MySchema.MyTable'
exec master.sys.sp_executesql @qry
```

I get an error stating that the table doesn't exist.

If I put the database name prefix before `MySchema.MyTable` name, i.e. `MyDb.MySchema.MyTable` the query runs correctly.

How can I avoid the error without specifying the database name in the dyanmic SQL?

Comment: Are you sure your DB context is correct? If your session is in a different DB, for example `master`, you will get this error

Comment: Yep, the session is in the right DB, but the way of executing it changed the context. Recursive's answer is right, but if you see mine you'll get extra explanation for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both answers by Recursive and koushik veldanda work fine, but this gives a deeper insight to the problem:

The problem is that executing a query with

```
exec master.sys.sp_execute_sql @qry
```

changes the context to the `master` database, so `MySchema.MyTable` is not accesible, because it doesn't belong to `master`, but to `MyDb`.

If the query is executed with

```
exec sys.sp_execute_sql @qry
```

the context is maintained in the current database, so the table is accesible, and the query runs without problem.

Answer (score 3):

try this!

change this

```
exec master.sys.sp_executesql @qry
```

to

```
exec sp_executesql @qry
```

or

```
exec @qry
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 exec @sql
```

is enough if there are any output parameters then go with

```
 exec sp_executesql
```